# How can I encrypt spark sql data frame column using SHA-2 and a random salt

Tags: scala, encryption, apache-spark-sql, salt, sha2

I am working in Scala programming language. I want to encrypt entire column of spark sql data frame using SHA-2 algorithm and a random salt

what I have so far is this and it works well

```
dataFrame.withColumn("ColumnName", sha2(bin(col("ColumnName")), 256))
```

How can I add salt to this hashing?

Thanks

Comment: It surely is a manner of speaking on your part, but you can not encrypt anything using SHA. You can hash, but not encrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.withColumn("ColumnName", 
              sha2(concat_ws("|", lit("left_salt"), bin(col("yourcoltocrypt")), lit("right_salt"))), 256))
```